# How to initialise a complex type in hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

A member of my class is of Type Byte. As you know its initial value would be `NULL`. But I want it to be `0` if no one calls constructor by default. So would the way I do it be the right way? Because in my database this value is not allowed to be `NULL`. So I need to give it a value which by default should be `0`.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Holiday")
public class Holiday {

   @Column(columnDefinition = "Bit(2)")
   private Byte approved = (byte) 0;

   public Holiday() {
   }

   public Holiday( Byte approved) {
      super();
      this.approved = approved;
   }
```

P.S.: Of course this class has many more members and also another constructor. But for demo I removed all the other members.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add *nullable = false*:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Holiday")
    public class Holiday {

        @Column(columnDefinition = "Bit(2)", nullable = false)
        private Byte approved = (byte) 0;

        public Holiday() {
        }

        public Holiday( Byte approved) {
            super();
            this.approved = approved;
        }
```

Or add in columnDefinition NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

```
 @Column(columnDefinition = "Bit(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
```

Answer (score 1):

> So would the way I do it be the right way?

Yes, it's right way. You can see a lot of similar examples in the hibernate documentation (especially for collections). I would suggest you to put this initialization in the default constructor and, if you have other constructors, call this constructor from them.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Holiday")
public class Holiday {

   @Column(columnDefinition = "Bit(2)")
   private Byte approved;

   public Holiday() {
      this.approved = 0;
      // other default initialization
   }

   public Holiday(Byte approved) {
      this();
      this.approved = approved;
   }
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use `columnDefinition`, you can define the default value there:

`columnDefinition = "Bit(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"`. This will set the constraint on the database level while rejecting NULL values.

If you would rather do it on the application level you can set it on the field instead, that's perfectly fine for default values.

Comment: DEFAULT 0 did not work for me. Maybe because I already have an existing table. Hibernate would only use that if table was create initally.

Comment: couldn't you add this constraint on the database then? or are you not allowed to modify the schema? in any case, you can just set the default value on the field level then, that's perfectly fine, but note that it will be possible to assign NULL values to that column via the database, or via the setter, so you have to take care of that, unless you set the `nullable=false` constraint in the `Column` annotation

Comment: Default only comes into play if it isn't included in the insert statement. Most JPA providers will pass through something because it is mapped, null if it hasn't been set, so the default usually only comes into play with non-JPA applications or JPA apps that don't map the column.